# How can I know whether a desktop environment is installed on Ubuntu through command line?

Tags: desktop-environments

How can I know whether a desktop environment is installed on Ubuntu? I can only access the computer remotely through command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are stored in `/usr/share/xsessions`.

Run this command:

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/xsessions
```

---

Example of output when at least one desktop environment is installed:

```
franck@server:~$ ls -l /usr/share/xsessions
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4294 Mar 21  2014 xfce.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5607 Jul 15  2014 xubuntu.desktop
```

Example of output when no desktop environment is installed:

```
franck@server:~$ ls -l /usr/share/xsessions
ls: cannot access '/usr/share/xsessions': No such file or directory
```